# Iterate DataTable And Update SQL Table

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

In my syntax below, I am creating a `datatable`, then populating the `datatable` with results from an `XML` API call.  Once the `List<string>` array has been fully processed, I want to iterate the `datatable` and update a `SQL Server 2008` table joining on the field `ID`  Below is my syntax, which does not throw any errors for me, but it is not updating the SQL Table either.  Can someone more skillful take a look and point out what I set-up incorrectly?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("fire",typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ice",typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("blue",typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("pink",typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("hot",typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("red",typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("d1",typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("t1",typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("d2",typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("t2",typeof(DateTime));
    List<string> random = new List<string>() { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Pink", "Hot", "Cold", "Orange" };

    foreach (var abc in random)
    {
        //API Call Here that returns my variables
        foreach (var stinkpot in xml.Descendants("APICall"))
        {
            fire = (string)stinkpot.Descendants("A").FirstOrDefault();
            ice = (string)stinkpot.Descendants("B").FirstOrDefault();
            blue = (string)stinkpot.Descendants("C").FirstOrDefault();
            pink = (string)stinkpot.Descendants("D").FirstOrDefault();
            hot = (string)stinkpot.Descendants("E").FirstOrDefault();
            red = (string)stinkpot.Descendants("F").FirstOrDefault();
            d1 = (string)stinkpot.Descendants("G").FirstOrDefault();
            t1 = (string)stinkpot.Descendants("H").FirstOrDefault();
            d2 = (string)stinkpot.Descendants("I").FirstOrDefault();
            t2 = (string)stinkpot.Descendants("J").FirstOrDefault();

            //Add variables to data table
            dt.Rows.Add(abc, fire, ice, blue, pink, hot, red, d1, t1, d2, t2);
        }  
    }

    //Update SQL Server Table Here
    foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            string updateCommand = "UPDATE sqltesttable SET [field1]=@fire, [field2] = @ice, [field3] = @blue, [field4] = @pink 
                                    ,[field5] = @hot, [field6] = @red, [field7] = @d1, [field8] = @t1, [field9] = @d2, [field10] = @t2
                                    WHERE ID = @id";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("csConnString"))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    comm.Connection = conn;
                    comm.CommandText = updateCommand;
                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fire", dtRow[fire].ToString();)
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ice", dtRow[ice].ToString();)
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blue", dtRow[blue].ToString();)
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pink", dtRow[pink].ToString();)
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hot", dtRow[hot].ToString();)
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@red", dtRow[red].ToString();)
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", dtRow[d1].ToString();)
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t1", dtRow[t1].ToString();)
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", dtRow[d2].ToString();)
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t2", dtRow[t2].ToString();)
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dtRow[id].ToString();)
                    try
                    {
                        comm.Open();
                        conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch(OleDbException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    } 
}
```

**EDIT**
This is the table structure, I know it is not good methodology to store date in one field and time in another, but this is data structure of a 3rd party app that we use that we have no control over.  The fields listed in this data structure are exactly as they are listed in my update statement.  `uqID` is the pk autonumber field, and `hlpID` is the unique identifier that is not a pk of the table.  The rest of the fields match up with `field1, field2` etc starting with `salestatus`

```
Create Table sqltesttable 
(
  uqID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
  ,hlpID int
  ,salestatus nvarchar(250)
  ,saletype nvarchar(250)
  ,salesperson nvarchar(500)
  ,salessupervisor nvarchar(500)
  ,commeligible bit
  ,dailygoalmet bit
  ,saledate datetime
  ,saletime datetime
  ,shipdate datetime
  ,shiptime datetime
)
```

Comment: I am not sure to understood what you are trying to do with this code, but for sure, whithout the @id parameter there is no update but only an exception

Comment: @Steve - the id in my where clause will mirror the id in the datatable.  Does that clarify?

Comment: You didn't add id parameter in comm instance

Comment: And how your database knows of this fact? A DataTable object is diconnected from your database and if you don't write a parameter for it the database will never guess. Usually these fields are IDENTITY and it is the database that fills them. By the way, I can't see where do you set a value for the ID field of the DataTable object.

Comment: @Steve - the SQL Table has a PK Autonumber field, both the SQL Table as well as the DataTable have an ID field that is a unique identifier that will for the DataTable be pulled from the API, and the SQL Table already exist.

Comment: this is rather messy and I would for starters suggest you create the Update statement inside of a stored procedure also you do not need this line `foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)` also where are you defining this `csConnString` can you also state what type of `Database` you are using?

Comment: csConnString is a class variable defined at the top of my procedure.  It is a valid SQL Server 2008 R2 Connection String.  The database I am using is a SQL Server 2008 R2 Database.  Messy?  What other than running the update from a stored procedure would you recommend?

Comment: why are you not using `SqlCommand, SqlConnection` also look into wrapping your sql objects around a `using() {}` and the foreach should be inside of that to take advantage of Auto Disposing of Objects can you also update this question and post what the Database Table Schema looks like please don't tell me you have column names as `Field1...Field10`

Comment: `dt.Rows.Add(abc, fire, ice, blue, pink, hot, red, d1, t1, d2, t2);` don't you want this inside the inner foreach loop..?

Comment: @MethodMan - syntax updated to properly show the .Add statment and SQL Data Structure

Comment: your update statement here `string updateCommand = "UPDATE sqltesttable SET [field1]` for example needs to have the same fields as in your table that you have created.. like I mentioned earlier create the update statement as a stored procedure and execute the stored procedure the same way changing your Command.Type = to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and change your Command Object to pass in the name of the stored procedure , connection string for example 
`using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("YourInsertCommandHere", connection))`